# Django: How to show second form on submit of first form without refreshing the page?

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi all I am trying to render a second form to template **without refreshing the page** when I click on submit button of first form. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: The only way to submit a form without refreshing the page is to use ajax.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I already done submit of one form using ajax without refresh. But now what I need is to display the second form without refresh. I tried to return the form using Jsonresponse, but it is failed due to form is not json serializable.